# Applying the Parameter Theorem to show that a function is not computable

Tags: computability

> Show that $g: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that
>   $$g(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if halt}(2833,x) \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
>   is not computable.

We know that

$$g(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }\Phi_x(2833)\downarrow \\ 0 & \text{if }\Phi_x(2833)\uparrow \end{cases}$$

How can I use the parameter theorem to reduce $g$ to $\text{halt}(x,x)$? I'm very confused.